# How to retrieve datasets from normalised shema in MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to retrieve datasets from a normalised MySQL 5.7 table shema where I am struggling to get the values.

There are 4 tables: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q2PJZVegdWXnpkotN2utu2/0

**Table1: articles**

```
article_id | title
1            First Car
2            Second Car
```

**Table2: articles_attr**

```
article_id | attr_id 
1            1
1            2
1            3
1            5
2            3
2            4
```

**Table3: attr_groups**

```
attr_id | attr_group_id | attribute
1         1               red
2         2               diesel
3         3               automatic
4         3               airbag
5         3               radio
```

**Table4: attr_groups_names**

```
attr_group_id | name
1               color
2               engine
3               features
```

Now I would like to retrieve all datasets (car1, car2, ..) with all attributes where the ones with multiple attributes per group get agregated.

e.g.

```
article_id | title | color | engine | features
1            Car 1   red     diesel   automatic,radio
2 ...
```

The amount of groups is huge (20+), so I would like to avoid to many joins.

My best shot:

```
SELECT 
    a.article_id, 
    a.title,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE attr.attr_group_id WHEN 26 THEN cat.attr_de END) AS functions,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE attr.attr_group_id WHEN 27 THEN cat.attr_de END) AS miscellaneous

FROM       articles_attr AS attr 
INNER JOIN articles a ON a.article_id = attr.article_id
INNER JOIN articles_attr AS cat ON cat.attr_id = attr.attr_id

GROUP BY   a.article_id
LIMIT 3
```

How can this be done?

Comment: What is the issue with your query?

Answer (score 1):

Your query has a correct basic structure, but your `CASE` expressions look somewhat off.  Try this version:

```
SELECT
    a.article_id,
    a.title,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN agn.name = 'color'    THEN ag.attribute END) color,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN agn.name = 'engine'   THEN ag.attribute END) engine,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN agn.name = 'features' THEN ag.attribute END) features
FROM articles a
INNER JOIN articles_attr aa
    ON a.article_id = aa.article_id
INNER JOIN attr_groups ag
    ON ag.attr_id = aa.attr_id
INNER JOIN attr_groups_names agn
    ON agn.attr_group_id = ag.attr_group_id
GROUP BY
    a.article_id,
    a.title;
```

[image]

### Demo

`GROUP_CONCAT` works here by ignoring `NULL` values in the aggregation, which then do not get added to the concatenated string.  Note also that depending on your MySQL version, you might have to `GROUP BY` both the `id` and `title` in the `articles` table.

Comment: Thank you, meanwhile I have created also a fiddle and updated the question. Is there a way to have the attribute groups created automatically and build from the groups names?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking me.